# userform with vlookup function from different sheets when i click an optionbutton for each lookup value

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, vlookup, radio-button

I have to know, is this possible that the single combo box that had a lists from 2 different sheets by using option buttons. this works well. but the vlookup function is working for sheet 1 only not sheet 2.
explanation:
in my userform, 
1 combobox = cmbbx1 
2 option buttons = 1.hq 2.whs 
2 textboxes = 1.txtbx1 2.txtbx2

When I click on the option button `hq` the list of `sheet1` is shown in combobox. then another 2 textboxes already coded with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`, so they're showing the given cell value.

but i can't make it work when i click on the option button `whs`. in this time combobox is showing the list from sheet2 but vlookup not working here.

here is the code what i get from another source for vlookup function.

```
Private Sub CmbBX1_AfterUpdate()
    'Check to see if value exists
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("B:B"), Me.CmbBX1.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Employee Not Registered"
        Me.CmbBX1.Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Lookup values based on control
    With Me
        .TxBx1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.CmbBX1, Sheet2.Range("Emp_ltl"), 2, 0)
        .TxBx2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.CmbBX1, Sheet2.Range("Emp_ltl"), 3, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

This is the code I used for the Option buttons:

```
Option Explicit

Public myList As Variant
Private Sub hq_Click()
myList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTL").Range("Emp_ltl").Value
Me.CmbBX1.List = myList
End Sub

Private Sub whs_Click()
myList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTS").Range("Emp_ltS").Value
Me.CmbBX1.List = myList
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you using the `hq` and `whs` in your code? The code above is only looking at Sheet2, maybe you should have an IF statement to vary a worksheet variable to change dynamically which sheet the Vlookup is looking at?

Comment: thanks Xabier, pls mentioned How can i use If variable. i will show u the optionbotton code here: `Option Explicit

Public myList As Variant
 Private Sub hq_Click()
 
 myList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTL").Range("Emp_ltl").Value
    
    Me.CmbBX1.List = myList
End Sub

Private Sub whs_Click()
 myList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTS").Range("Emp_ltS").Value
    
    Me.CmbBX1.List = myList
End Sub`

Comment: sorry! i am new to this post. my codes are not entered properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like the following will do it:

```
Private Sub CmbBX1_AfterUpdate()
    If hq.Value = True Then 'check if hq is selected
        Dim ws As Worksheets: Set ws = Worksheets("LTL") 'declare your worksheet and your range
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("Emp_ltl")
        myList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTL").Range("Emp_ltl").Value
        Me.CmbBX1.List = myList
    ElseIf whs.Value = True Then 'if whs is selected
        Dim ws As Worksheets: Set ws = Worksheets("LTS") 'declare and set your worksheet and range
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("Emp_ltS")
        myList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LTS").Range("Emp_ltS").Value
        Me.CmbBX1.List = myLis
    Else
        MsgBox "No Option has been selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Check to see if value exists
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B:B"), Me.CmbBX1.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Employee Not Registered"
        Me.CmbBX1.Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Lookup values based on control
    With Me
        .TxBx1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.CmbBX1, rng, 2, 0)
        .TxBx2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.CmbBX1, rng, 3, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hi xabier! thanks for your code and time, there is a big issue. now combobox not showing the list. i just need vlookup function should work from 2 different sheets in same combobox. <br/> i put the sheet 2 code in my last post. but same code for sheet 3 also. please make it work.

Comment: @mohammadIlyas updated my answer to include the update of your Combobox, I'm not sure what you mean by Sheet 2 and Sheet 3, the above code looks at Sheets LTL & LTS...?

Comment: thanks for your help xabier. I had done my own like u said I used if statement. then it works well. thanks again. I tried your code. it doesn't work for my wish. because of i had to change my all codes and methods.